# show total wordpress users with a custom user meta

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

When users join my wordpress site a referral id (which is the user's id who referred them) labeled as "ref" is added to their profile during registration.

example: http://site.com/?v=(userid)

Anyone who joins under this id is tagged to that user and I'd like to display the total referrals who joined under their id and emails but out of all the examples I found, I can only display the meta info and not the total. Any suggestions?

Here's what I have so far...

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); //get logged in user
$uid = $current_user->ID; // get their id

// WP_User_Query arguments
$args = array (
'meta_query'     => array(
    array(
    'key'       => 'ref',
    'value'     => '$uid',
    'compare'   => '=',
    'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
    ),
    ),
    'count_total'    => true,
    'fields'         => array( 'user_email' ),
);

// The User Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
    echo '<p>' . $user->user_email . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
```

}

Comment: Are you sure what you need is not `count($user_query->results)`?

Comment: The screen goes blank when I tried it.

Comment: How did you try it? I assumed you know basic PHP debugging.

Comment: No, I'm a newbie. I changed out    if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
 to if ( ! empty( count($user_query->results) ) ) {

Comment: That code was OK for printing out the individual results. You also need the count of those results, right? So, inside that `if`, where you know you have _some_ results, you can `echo count($user_query->results);` to find out exactly how many of them there are.